# How to add specific year to datetime output while converting mm/dd in C#

Tags: c#

i have a string in mm/dd format. For example "**04/13**"
need to convert to DateTime.

When we use Convert.ToDateTime("04/13"), it gives output as

4/13/**2022** 12:00:00 AM with year as current year that is 2022

Instead of current year 2022, need to get custom year like '**1900**' in output or whichever year is configured

my desired output is 4/13/**1900** 12:00:00 AM. can someone help on this

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime("04/13").AddYears(-DateTime.Today.Year + <<Required Configure Year>>)`. Note the configured year can lead to edge case for those years which are not leap year if you are converting `2/29`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method to this:

```
public static DateTime GetDate(string text, int year, int hour = 0, int min = 0, int sec = 0)
{
    var str = $"{year}/{text} {hour:D2}:{min:D2}:{sec:D2}";
    return DateTime.ParseExact(
        str, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

And use it:

```
var date = GetDate("04/13", 1900, 12);      
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice and easy

```
var year = "1900";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact($"04/13/{year}", "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I do notice you've specified '12:00:00' as the time you want in your output, but not mentioned any more information on this, so I haven't included it, but it's very similar to what I've done above, except you would add on your time.

Comment: Thanks DubDub for the answer, i am just concerned about year

Answer (score 0):

To get your desired output, you could just do:

```
Convert.ToDateTime("4/13").AddYears(- desiredYearsToSubtract);
```

Then just add the desired years to subtract to your configuration.

Comment: Thanks @Pharnax for the quick response, logic looks fine but desiredYearsToSubtract should be updated for each year